# Incrementing a field + 1

Tags: apex

trying to add a simple incrementation to a field. Autonumber won't work because certain logic has to fire on other field values, so im doing this in a trigger.

Basically i thought this would work

myobject = myobject +1;

but it doesn't. Its adding a '1' to the field after every time it fires (which makes sense). So it ends up being myobjectfieldvalue1, and then myobjectfieldvalue11, myobjectfieldvalue111, and so on

It's probably something super simple I'm missing here, can anyone tell me how to increment values on a save? Once again, I don't think the autonumber will work for me here because I need to be doing logic in the background on the insert of this value.

Comment: What is the type of field? If you want to increment you should use `Number`, not `Text.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the field type is text, not a number. Otherwise you shouldn't be getting the result.

The solutions:

1. As Adrian Larson has pointed out, use a number field instead of a text field.
2. If, for some reason, you don't want to change the type of existing field, try the following code.

```
    Integer fieldNumber = Integer.ValueOf(yourfield__c.trim());
    fieldNumber++;
    yourfield__c = '' + fieldNumber;
```